# Why do we need nodejs installed to run typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, angular, npm

Why is it so because to transpile typesccript into javascript we need tsc, so far so good, but we run our transpiled code in the browser not locally so why we need node js installed before installing typescript

Comment: node.js is becoming code heavy for developers, it doesn't have something like node.jquery

Comment: @Leroy its not about performance or which one should use, im trying to understand why do we need it anyway

Comment: Umm, I think it has to do with version control ideals, typescript conversions changes from time to time I use Visual Studio Code and let me know of updates and node.js has networking and may inform you that the typescript version is depreciated because of ECMASCRIPT changes or version.

Comment: from what I can see, typescript is written in node.js, it's installed using npm, which is a nodejs package manager, - so, it stands to reason you need node.js to install tsc so you can transpile your code - am I missing something from the question?

Comment: @Jaromanda What do you mean by typescript written in node.js

Comment: I mean it's written in javascript using the node.js platform for want of a better term - running tsc runs `node.js lib/tsc.js` - it's just a node app

Comment: Okay, :) Now i understand this @JaromandaX

Comment: @JaromandaX: Make that an answer. That's the correct answer - the typescript compiler, tsc, is a node.js application.

Answer (score 0):

@blackHawk, So basically we are using npm modules to transpile the typescript. Its essentially just a tool. You can even use Webstorm to transpile and generate js code. Either way you would want to transpile the code from typescript files into JS files and bundle it and sent to the browser.

Comment: This answer should be a comment